# sklearn One Hot Encoder without fitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a sequence of data that I already know the categories. Is there anyway to use sklearn's `OneHotEncoder` without fitting?

Specifically, I have already initialized the Encoder:

```
my_cat = ['a', 'b', 'c']
enc = OneHotEncoder(categories=[my_cat])
```

However, I am unable to use the encoder, unless I fit it with some dummy values:

```
enc.fit([['a']])
enc.transform([['a'], ['c']]).toarray()
>>>
[[1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

If I do not fit the encoder first,

```
# Missing enc.fit
enc.transform([['a'], ['c']]).toarray()
```

there will be the following error,

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

despite that I have already explicitly passed the categories to the encoder. This error is thrown by the method `check_is_fitted()`.

Am I using `OneHotEncoder` for the wrong thing? What are some other methods to perform a dumb mapping, or should I just write my own?

Comment: you can see [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#L437) for `fit()` and you can see it runs many lines of code - so it seems it has to do something more then only assign categories.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by one hot encoder without fitting. Can you show me some expected result?

Comment: @jasonwong thank you, I have updated the question, hope this is clearer.

Comment: You need to know that `fit()` is some standard syntax in sklearn. Basically every model in sklearn has the `fit()` method, such as `LinearRegression, svm, StandardScaler, LogisticRegression`, so does this one. I would say `fit` is necessary and `categories` is a bonus feature. If you really feel uncomfortable using `fit()`, you can try `fit_transform()`.